# const variable paradox

Tags: c++, programming-languages, constants

if I have some expression on c++:

```
const int x = 3;
```

can I say that x is a variable? It seems very strange cause x is not variable cause I can't change it, thanks in advance for any expanations

**Edited**
P.S. thanks for all answers, I understood that by definition of C++, answer for my question may be yes, do You know some other languages, in which the answer for my question will be no?

Comment: I was expecting a post about a variable that traveled back in time and changed its own declaration to `const`.

Comment: Variable by what definition?  The C++ standard, or the English language?

Comment: The word "variable" implies "something that varies", but that's not the formal C++ definition.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: That may be its original definition in English. To me its meaning in the context of a computer language it means `named object`.

Comment: "Constants aren't. Variables don't." -- who said that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  `x` is a variable, even though you cannot (legitimately) change its value.

Effectively, in C++, an object that has a name is a "variable."

Comment: I'd have to disagree (although not voting down). A constant is NOT a variable; it's a constant, and "any object that has a name" is incorrect as well (an int constant is not an object). ;-) By your logic, a #DEFINE would also be a variable, because I can #DEFINE aVar, giving it a name (aVar).

Comment: @Ken: `aVar` is not a variable because it is not a named object (it is the name of a macro). A `const int` is indeed an object and can be used as an object (e.g., you can take its address). The C++ Standard states: "A variable is introduced by the declaration of an object. The variable's name denotes the object" (3/4). You can certainly disagree about the meaning of the word "variable" in general, but in C++ it has a specific meaning (technically that meaning is changing in C++0x so that most references can also be rightly referred to as variables).

Comment: Just hopefully clearing up things, Bjarne originally used the word `readonly` instead of `const`. Thinking about a readonly variable is perhaps easier.

Comment: @Ken: You can disagree all you like, but in the language definition it is a "const variable"

Comment: Slight nitpick, there can be *unnamed* variables, there is at least one place in the current standard where they are mentioned, and while I could not imagine how that could be, @litb provided a simple example: an unnamed parameter to a function declares a variable that has no name --with the usual caveats with references...

Answer (score 1):

This is philosophical , it cannot be modifiable, in fact some compiler like GCC stores it in the Text-section.
So or is a non-modifiable variable, or a constant.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ terminology the term *variable* is almost synonymous with the term *object*: any *declared object* is a *variable*. Whether the object is changeable or not makes no difference. So, within the official terminology yes, `x` is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the ISO language definition for C++ such an object is referred to as a *const variable*, meaning a *read-only* variable.  In conceptual terms and in natural language semantics it is a nonetheless constant.

I imagine the term is merely used to differentiate a *constant object* (such as `x` in your example) from a *literal constant*, (such as 3), where one is an addressable object, and the other is not.  The term `const object` is not used because an *object* refers to the instance in memory, while a *variable* refers a name or identifier associated with an object.

Answer (score 0):

BTW it is useful for a function declaration, for example

```
void ReadStuff(const int a)
```

This means that you actually can give the function a non static variable but
it will be treated as a constant (ie. the function will not change it).

Comment: A top-level const qualifier like this one actually has no effect on function declarations in general; this declaration is exactly identical to `void ReadStuff(int a)`. Top-level const qualifiers only have an effect when they appear in the definition of the function.  (I don't know what you mean by "a non static variable;" what does static have to do with this?)