# C++ - constant variable, is it a correct term?

Tags: c++, variables, constants

At the end of the artile here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/45-enumerated-types/

It mentions the following sentence:

*Finally, as with **constant variables**, enumerated types show up in the debugger, making them more useful than #defined values in this regard.*

Is "constant variables" a correct term to use? Aren't constants different from variables?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695766/const-variable-paradox/4696060#4696060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant is a variable. In C++ (and most languages), defining a variable as a constant simply tells the compiler that the variable is not allowed to be changed.

Comment: Actually this is not true, do not confuse C and C++ as being "most languages". In ML languages, "constants" are called bindings, and they're names of values. They're also called variables because they can be created dynamically.

Answer (score 8):

It is a *variable* in the sense that it is an addressable object, as opposed to a *literal constant* which is not addressable.

It is perhaps contradictory, but the language standard uses the term variable to refer to addressable objects in general, and `const` to specify a *read-only* addressable object.

Answer (score 5):

Constants in C++ are a special kind of variable. I understand it may sound contradictory for the common sense, but that's how it is in C++.

```
int var1 = 1;
int const var2 = 2;
```

The difference between them is only the `const` keyword, which tells the compiler that the value of `var2` must not be changed once it is created:

```
var1 = 2; // fine
var2 = 1; // compilation error!
```

This simple rule also causes further constraints to be enforced for `const` variables, e.g. you can't create a non-`const` reference to a `const` variable (as otherwise you could still change its value via that reference). Neither you are allowed to pass `var2` to a function with a signature `f(int& i)`, for the same reason. However, you can create `const` references to them, use their values etc. just as with any "normal" variable. So by and large they are like any other variable.

Comment: Constants are not a special kind of variable. You should learn to write you declarations properly: `int const var2 = 2;` Do not put the `const` first. What this means is a variable which is an int const-lvalue, which might have been written `int const&` and please note it is the reference (or lvalue) which is `const` and not the `int` (no matter what the Standard says, it confuses semantics with syntax). Therefore the `const`ness is type information (unfortunately) just as `reference` aka `lvalue` is type information. It isn't a special variable kind (unfortunately).

Comment: @Yttrill: whether it's type information or not, and regardless of how you prefer to write your definitions, it's still a "special kind of variable", in the sense that it's a special case of a more general concept. Pointer variables are a special kind of variable. Globals are a special kind of variable. They're special in different ways. Constants are a special kind of variable - specifically those with a const qualification at the top level of their type. At least, they are unless you want to refer to both constant variables and literals as "constants".

Comment: @Yttrill, the variable in my example is not a reference (nor a pointer), thus AFAIK there should be no semantical difference (but I may be wrong of course, my C++ is rusty). I fixed the order nevertheless for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a bit of a contradiction in terms. Variables are things that vary by definition, and constants are things that don't vary by definition.

That aside, in C++ (and other languages), people still call them constant variables because we essentially think of any value with a name as a variable.

Feel free to just say 'constant' though.

Comment: ...Except 'constant' alone does not distinguish a *constant object* from a *literal constant*.

Comment: True, but if you want to refer to a literal then you can just say 'literal' :) (also, ambiguity can be useful if you explicitly do not want to distinguish between the two -- which is usually the case).

Comment: @Clifford: The best and worst part about "natural" communication, which is where you'd just say "constant" as above, is you don't have to be as precise as in a programming language; context and experience will nearly always distinguish the meaning, when it even matters.

Answer (score 1):

It is an obvious contradiction in terms on the surface, and has probably come about for historical reasons ("variable" being used to refer to a memory location associated with a name and a type).

However, I can try to justify the term:
At compile time, it is an variable - before optimization, it has all the properties a variable has - takes up memory, has a location and so on - and is handled much the same. (In contrast, an value you provide like 43423L, 3.141 or a literal "somestring" is not a variable.)
At *runtime*, it cannot be changed anymore, and is seen as constant. It's sort of a "write-once variable", which you set in the source.

Answer (score 0):

So many people are confused. In K&R C, a string literal can be changed. Hence, literals being constants meaning immutable is wrong. In ISO C and C++ variables of type T const for some T can also be changed, using a cast. So again, constant doesn't mean immutable. As @foo pointed out above, constants often do not have the properties of a variable because of optimisation, and in fact the semantics often specify it. Also do not forget in C and C++ there are *constant expressions* sometimes known as compile-time constants, used for array bounds, for example, a kind of constant which would never be confused with a variable, agree?

So here's a definition: a constant is a *binding of a name to a value*. With this definition, `1` is a constant because it is a literal name, and the binding is implicit. And here

```
enum {x};
void f();
```

there are two constants, namely `x` and `f`: these are bindings of symbol names (in this case both identifiers, in C++ `operator+` is also a name but not an identifier).

Now, I will show you another constant which will surprise you!

```
int y = 1;
```

Yes indeed, `y` is a constant too! It is a binding of the name `y` to an address.
[If on the stack, an offset from the frame base instead]

So actually pretty much everything in your abstract syntax is a constant if you think about it hard enough :)